# Iterate over a class composed of other classes

Tags: python, oop

I have a structure representing some data in a following way:

```
class GenericDataHolder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.xxx=[] 
        self.yyy=[]

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1=GenericDataHolder()
        self.a2=GenericDataHolder()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b1=GenericDataHolder()
        self.b2=GenericDataHolder()
        self.b3=A()
```

I would like to iterate over `class B` elements so that i will be able to access all nested objects like below:

```
b=B()
for i in b:
    print i.xxx
    print i.yyy
```

I have read that there are a few possible solutions to solve this:

- using metaclass
- implementing iterator protocol
- using itertools

This is all fine on basic examples, but I couldn't find any solution to the problem I am facing directly - having class which's elements are composed of other classes.

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is the `dir()` builtin which provides a list of the object's methods and attributes.
You can then sort through them, for instance `not attr.startswith('_')` and `not callable(getattr(obj, attr))`

Comment: @immortal you probably should just use the `__dict__` attribute, and use `vars` to access it in that case instead of `dir`

Comment: In your example though, `b` doesn't have `xxx` and `yyy` properties; it has `b1` and `b2`, *each* of which has those properties. So what is the exact behaviour you want?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think `vars` will give you much of an advantage here, but it's also an eligible solution

Comment: @immortal well, you wouldn't have to check `attr.startswith('_')` nor `callable(attr)`, since `vars` returns the underlying instance `__dict__`, which only contains the instance variables

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I stand corrected

Comment: @immortal yea, `dir` is mostly there for convenience, even [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) state "Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases."

Comment: @daniel roseman, exactly, maybe some recursion could be adapter Here ? There is Max 2 levels of „nested” objects until we reach GenericDataHolder()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` uses the (internal equivalent of the) [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) on the object to get an iterator. Implement the [`__iter__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) to produce one:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b1 = GenericDataHolder()
        self.b2 = GenericDataHolder()
        self.b3 = A()

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.b1
        yield self.b2
        yield from iter(self.b3)  # use `for sub in self.b3: yield sub` in Python 2
```

I used a *generator function* to produce an iterator; when `__iter__` is called a generator object is created that then produces `b1` and `b2` in order.

The (Python 3) `yield from` syntax then delegates to all such values in `b3`, which also needs to implement the protocol:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1 = GenericDataHolder()
        self.a2 = GenericDataHolder()

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.a1
        yield self.a2
```

Alternatively, `B.__iter__` could just reach into `self.b3` and `yield self.b3.a1` and `self.b3.a2`, and not delegate.

Comment: Important to note `yield from` is Python 3 syntax

Comment: @immortal: which is the gold standard right now; I've added a comment to show what to use in Python 2.

Comment: It might be gold standard, but all of the real-world applications I've worked with were and are written and maintained in Python 2, which is unlikely to change for a while.

Comment: @immortal: my experience is different; at Facebook we are aggressively replacing Python 2 code with Python 3 (and all new code must be in Python 3).

Comment: @immortal: Python 2 is reaching EOL in under 3 years, there is still time to not get left behind!

Comment: Kudos to FB then :)
Unfortunately not all companies out there are FB or have it's resources to do such an aggressive refactoring of their code...
Just as a reminder, COBOL and FORTRAN are still very much with us to this day, I wouldn't be surprised to see Python 2 developers in as high a demand in 30 years as COBOL experts are now...